# Booting from USB in samsung z700,

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb, usb-boot

I know there are many resources online that show you how to boot from a USB, but I can't seem to find a solution. For the past week, I have been trying to figure this out but can't. So this is my problem:
I have taken all (that I thought) necessary steps. This is what my bios look like. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Bios]
[image: Boot]

since I can't add more pictures, my boot order is this

1. USB HDD
2. USB FDD
3. USB CD
4. SATA CD: Matshita DVD-RAM
5. SATA HDD: Hitachi
6. Network

My USB drive is EFI bootable (it is FAT32 and BOOTX64.EFI is present), I also used the drive to boot on my other laptop and it works just fine. It's only this laptop that is causing problems. Are there any inherent features blocked by Samsung that are not letting me do this?

What can I do?

Comment: Try setting `legacy USB support` to `disabled` maybe. Also it could be 32-bit UEFI.

Comment: When I did that, no power went to the USB drive